# How to flatten lists in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hi I have a DataFrame like this
It is a table of a sales information with row index of product brand and column index of Price,Week and Timestamp.

```py
timeperiod = pd.date_range(start='4/15/2019', periods=3,dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='D')
df = pd.DataFrame({'Price':[[2000,2000,2000],[1000,1000,1000]],'Week':[[0,0,1],[0,0,1]],
                   'Timestamp': [timeperiod,timeperiod]},index = ['Apple','Huawei'])
```

The output  of the code above is:

```
         Price              Timestamp                                         Week
Apple   [2000, 2000, 2000]  DatetimeIndex(['2019-04-15', '2019-04-16', '20...   [0, 0, 1]
Huawei  [1000, 1000, 1000]  DatetimeIndex(['2019-04-15', '2019-04-16', '20...   [0, 0, 1]
```

Now I want to flatten the dataframe to **three columns** [Price,Timestamp and Week ]**with index of a series of number** [0,1,2] (since i got 3 element in list), and store in **Two dataframes**,which were named after the original dataframe index, Apple and Huawei.

so the outcome should be

```py
Apple = pd.DataFrame({'Price':[2000,2000,2000],'Week':[0,0,1],
                   'Timestamp': timeperiod})
Huawei = pd.DataFrame({'Price':[1000,1000,1000],'Week':[0,0,1],
                   'Timestamp': timeperiod})
```

```
Apple:
   Price  Timestamp  Week
0   2000 2019-04-15     0
1   2000 2019-04-16     0
2   2000 2019-04-17     1

Huawei:
   Price  Timestamp  Week
0   1000 2019-04-15     0
1   1000 2019-04-16     0
2   1000 2019-04-17     1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51752361/9081267) function from other answer, we can unnest your columns one by one and concatenating them together again:

```
df = pd.concat([explode_list(df, col)[col] for col in df.columns], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
        Price  Week  Timestamp
Apple    2000     0 2019-04-15
Apple    2000     0 2019-04-16
Apple    2000     1 2019-04-17
Huawei   1000     0 2019-04-15
Huawei   1000     0 2019-04-16
Huawei   1000     1 2019-04-17
```

---

Finally if you want seperate dataframes for each unique index, we can use `groupby`:

```
dfs = [d for _, d in df.groupby(df.index)]

dfs[0]
print('\n')
dfs[1]
```

Output:

```
       Price  Week  Timestamp
Apple   2000     0 2019-04-15
Apple   2000     0 2019-04-16
Apple   2000     1 2019-04-17

        Price  Week  Timestamp
Huawei   1000     0 2019-04-15
Huawei   1000     0 2019-04-16
Huawei   1000     1 2019-04-17
```

---

Function used from linked answer:

```
def explode_list(df, col):
    s = df[col]
    i = np.arange(len(s)).repeat(s.str.len())
    return df.iloc[i].assign(**{col: np.concatenate(s)})
```

Comment: Hi @Erfan Thanks your answer i am working on understanding the code you provide. however i have no idea of this [d for _, d in df.groupby(df.index)]

Answer (score 0):

```py
def explode(series): 
    return pd.DataFrame(dict(series.iteritems()))

for index, row in df.iterrows(): 
    print(index)
    print(explode(row))
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.